# Update instance for author in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to update a instance of a model only if the request author is same than instance author.

I guess can do it in the update method:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user == self.get_object().user
        do_things()
```

How can I do it? Is it obligatory to write an update en every ModelViewSet or ListAPIView? or is there a method to write a custom permission to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a [custom permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). The following example is from the docs, modified to fit your use case:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    Assumes the model instance has an `user` attribute.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Instance must have an attribute named `user`.
        return obj.user == request.user
```